# Python load in from another python file

Tags: python-3.x

I am wanting to loop through 5 questions from another `.py` file.

The extra file is `file.py` and has 5 questions `-q1 = "what is..."`, `q2` etc..
This adds a number to each time I use `q` but does not catch the question from the external python document:

```
from file import*
i = 0
for x in range(5):
    i = i+1
    question1 = str(input("q" + str(i)))
```

Comment: This is why numbered variable names are discouraged. Defining `q = ["what is...", "where is...", "who is..."]` would allow you to use `q[0], q[1], q[2]`.

Comment: Hi Skoobay, if my answer helped you, could you consider marking it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to save the questions in file.py as a list as suggested in the comments. Then the contents of file.py would be:

```
q = ['who is...', 'What is...']
```

and the content of your program would be:

```
from file import q
for item in q:
    print(item)
```

If you want to do it your way, do it like this:

```
from file import *

for x in range(5):
    exec('question = q' + str(x+1))
    print(question)
```

However, this is not pythonic and not recommended.